# Gradle, 'url' cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

Since some time, on any `maven { url "whatever" }`  I'm getting this warning:

[image: Imgur]

[Here](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/glm) a sample project experiencing the issue

It's not critical neither a blocker, but it's kind of annoying

Does anybody know where it comes from?

Specs:

- Idea IU 181.3263.15
- JRE 1.8.0_152
- kotlin 1.2.21
- gradle 4.4.1
- Win 7 x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your IDE is analyzing the Gradle DSL. With fully expanded syntax, your code looks like this:

```
project.dependencies({(RepositoryHandler handler) -> {
   handler.maven({(MavenArtifactRepository repository) -> {
       repository.setUrl("https://...");
   });
};
```

If you look in the Gradle API, you can see that `MavenArtifactRepository` has two methods:

```
void    setUrl(Object url)
void    setUrl(URI url)
```

So the IDE is saying you should pass `Object` or an `URI`. If you use `setUri(...)` the annoying IDE warning should go away.

Comment: I don't know why, but now it complains `url uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")`. This works `setUrl("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")` though

Comment: Because groovy is a dynamic language, IDEs can often only guess about typing correctness. I cannot say why setUrl() works in your case but url does not. Glad it works now anyway.

Answer (score 24):

To make IntelliJ IDEA stop complaining, you can use:

```
maven {
    url = 'http://myrepo'
}
```

which I believe is the Groovy shortcut for `setUrl('http://myrepo')`.